# Is constraints important for for select?

Tags: oracle

I have `table` on `database1` with some `constraints` like `primary key` and `check`. I have all my logic on this database for insert data in this `table`, then I need this table on `database2` to just select data.

So I made replication for this table using `database links` (select data from `database1` insert data into `database2`), from `database1` to `database2`. I made this table on `database2` without `constraints`, I just create  `index` on the `fields` which I need in my `select's` `where` clause.

Is there any reason why I need to create same constraints(`primary key` and `checks`) on `database2`, when I need this table just for select on this base? Maybe it gets performance difference?

Comment: The optimizer uses foreign key and check constraints to e.g. remove redundant joins.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any reason why I need to create same constraints(primary key
>   and checks) on database2, when I need this table just for select on
>   this base? Maybe it gets performance difference?

There is no need to have same constraints on your table in database2 until you are not populating that table other that source table of database1 which is having constraints. This is because all validation is already been done while inserting records to table of database1. There is no performance related improvement with constraints addition. Indexing table of database2 will help in performance.

Comment: If i don't need any other constraints why do I need `PK` or `Unique key`?

Comment: @Gog1nA How you created index? I mean its good to have some PK or Unique key before creating index. If you dont need you can ignore that .